# jquery before(), a recurrence function issue

Tags: jquery, recurrence

I want to duplicate a div with a class "test2", by clicking on it, with the function before(). The click will also remove the class "test2" on the originel div, and if the user click again on the originel div an alert('ok') will appear. It's working well but if I'm duplicating n times the div, and if I'm clicking one time on the originel div, alert('ok'); will be all n times.

My code is :

```
<div class="test1 test2">message</div>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {

function test() {
    $('.test1').click(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('test2')){
                $(this).before('<div class="test1 test2">message</div>');
                $(this).removeClass('test2');
            }
            else{
                alert('ok');
            }
    test(); 
    });

}

test();

});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/manguo_manguo/TNeYk/

Comment: Why do you have your event handler wrapped inside of the test function? And why are you calling the test function from within itself again?

Comment: because I want to copy "<div class="test1 test2">message</div>", And i'm calling the test function within itself because I want to apply the test function on the div I just created

Comment: I think you want to use the term "recursive," not "recurrence." "Recurrence" appears more in the context of mathematics.

Comment: yes @JohnFlatness it might be the good term, I'm editing the post, thanks

Comment: Check if this fiddle does what you want to do? http://jsfiddle.net/TNeYk/1/

Comment: Every time you run the test() function, a new click event is bound to the elements that exists on your page, so when you click on one of the new elements, several click events are attached, and the alert pops up one time for each click event, and you're running the test() function inside the test() function, making it somewhat recursive.

Comment: yeah it does !!! thanks a lot !! I will inform myself about on('click', '.test1'
thanks again

Comment: thanks @adeneo but how come the result is not the same with on('click', '.test1' ???

Comment: The fiddle from @ryadavilli uses a delegated event handler. The click event is registered to the document, and since events bubble, it just needs to check if the element matches the selector, that's why it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one: [**here at fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TNeYk/2/)

```
 function test() {
   var i=1;
   $(document).on('click', '.test1', function () {
       if ($(this).hasClass('test2')) {
          $(this).before('<div class="test1 test2">message'+ i++ +'</div>');
          $(this).removeClass('test2')
       } else {
          alert('ok');
       }
   });
}
$(function () {
   test();
});
```